# Why split data into multi-tables doesn't improve performance?

Tags: mysql, architecture

We are using mysql. We have a huge table which contains 1 billion rows. The engine is InnoDB. And we have 50% SELECT, 30% UPDATE, OTHER 20% per minute. We want to improve the performance, so we split the single table into multi ones. But by splitting, we saw the performance didn't improved a bit. Why? Is it the common sense that split table will improve performance?

The server is 4-core, SCSI RAID 5 Hard Disk, 32GB memory. Just one single server.

Comment: Would need more information on your use cases. I think normally splitting the rows shows a performance increase when you have a recent table (with a much smaller number of records) and then an archive table - that is hit on much rarer occasions. Thinking of looking at your credit card online. Recent transations would be in table 1, and table 2 would have your whole history past recent. You look at recent all the time, but history much less frequently. Note that when needing to look at the archives you've gained no improvement.

Comment: The table is used for user subscription information. Which is, a new user(cellphone number) subscribe a service, then we insert a row in this table. If a user already in our platform, then we update the table, if a user want to unsubscribe a service, we also update his/her record.

Comment: So to insert a user, must you now check across two tables to see if the user exists? And to update, check both tables to see if the user exists and then insert? How are you splitting the tables - what's your method for that?

Comment: Sharding would likely give you performance improvements by splitting records across multiple servers, but it's not clear what you've done.  I would investigate schema optimization, server configuration, adding memory, and switching to RAID10, probably in that order.

Comment: Actually, I split tables/databases in just one server. So I doubt this is because server's IO is already full, which is no use to split...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info in your question: You have a single RAID Set.

So when you had the single table it was on that RAID Set. When you split the table, both of the new tables were on the same RAID Set. So you get no performance benefit.

You actually get a performance hit since you now have to handle 2 tables.

To get a performance boost you need minimum to put the data on different disks, preferably use sharding to place the data on different servers.

For some comparison see: http://xeround.com/blog/2011/11/mysql-sharding-vs-mysql-partitioning